# How to place a div at the end of the other div using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place child div inside parent div which is a Flexbox such that I want the child div to be placed some space at the end of parent div.

What I am trying to do:

```css
.outermost_div {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.button_div {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top: 9px solid white;
  border-bottom: 9px solid white;
}

.outermost_div.additional {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="outermost_div additional">
  <div className="save_div">
    <button className="button_div" onClick={ props.on_selected}Save</button>
    <div className="divider" />
    <button className="button_div" onClick={props.on_cancel}>
        Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first picture below shows the output for the code above and the second picture is how I want it to be.

[image]

Comment: Your code centers the elements, it doesn't push them to the end

Comment: typo updated the code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
   .outermost_div.additional {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end; --added this
    padding-right: 60px; --added this
}
```

```css
.outermost_div {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;

    .button_div {
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
    }

    .divider {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1px;
        height: 40px;
        border-top: 9px solid white;
        border-bottom: 9px solid white;
    }
}

.outermost_div.additional {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
     padding-right: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost_div additional">
    <div class="save_div">
        <button class="button_div" onClick= 
            {props.on_selected} Save</button>
        <div class="divider"/>
        <button class="button_div" onClick={props.on_cancel}>
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. i want some space after the cancel button to the right.

Comment: @pete what are you trying to say??

Comment: @stackoverflow_user. i have updated the answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you add a little `margin-right` to the cancel button (along with `justify-content: flex-end` on the `save_div`). This will give you the look you are looking for.

```css
.save_div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

button.button_div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost_div additional">
  <div class="save_div">
    <button class="button_div" onClick={ props.on_selected}Save</button>
    <div class="divider" />
    <button class="button_div" onClick={props.on_cancel}>
                Cancel
            </button>
  </div>
</div>
```